# Nightwatch.js - Use the same browser session

Tags: selenium, nightwatch.js

We would love to adopt `Nightwatch.js` for testing on browsers, but we're stuck on one major caveat: at the time of this writing, Nightwatchjs does not support running different tests using the same browser session. In short, it means that:

- Creating the browser session is handled by the Nightwatch module from [lib/index.js](https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/blob/0aeaf4275028ccb78eae2544ecd343f610aed4c8/lib/index.js), in the [startSession](https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/blob/0aeaf4275028ccb78eae2544ecd343f610aed4c8/lib/index.js#L180) function;
- Killing the browser would correspond to the *delete* command place in the `Selenium` action queue in the terminate function of that module;
- A new Nightwatch client is created at every test run, which happens every time we load a different test file;

According to [this source](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/1988/selenium-reuse-existing-browser-session-instead-of-opening-new-windows), it is possible to reuse the current browser session in Selenium, instead of opening a new window.

**Has anyone managed to fix this problem in Nightwatch?**

Here's the [feature request on Github](https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/issues/117), which was requested on Mar 31, 2014 and is still open.

Another approach would be to *circumvent the problem altogether by getting Nightwatch to merge all different files into one Test Suite*, but that seems to be harder to solve than the problem with sessions...

Comment: I have come up with a solution that runs all the tests in one browser session. It does not solve the problem but it did the trick for me: https://github.com/dreamyguy/sidhree-com/commit/67d5a492a6e5d895a33905868d5298d57b352e9d

The idea is to flatten all tests to one folder, require every file in a single one and run Nightwatch against that file. In this case `./bin/nightwatch --test tests/browser/nightwatch.js`.

Comment: For running different tests, you can use nightwatch-cucumber, you can set up scenarios, so the whole session can has many scenarios(each one is a test) :https://github.com/mucsi96/nightwatch-cucumber/ , and it does all tests in a browser session.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reuse the browser session for Selenium WebDriver for Nightwatch.js tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27026363/reuse-the-browser-session-for-selenium-webdriver-for-nightwatch-js-tests)

Comment: what @WallaceSidhrée suggested did the trick case. congrats!

Comment: Do you need to run your tests in an already open browser?

Comment: I did the same thing that @Raymond did, you have the before, after, beforeEach and afterEach hooks, that let you control if you want a new session for the current tests or not

Answer (score 3):

Nightwatch now has support for resuing browser sessions. You can simply use the flag `--reuse-browser` to reuse sessions while running your nightwatch tests.