# how to use "session/sessionId" to use single browser session across the execution?

Tags: javascript, selenium, session, nightwatch.js

I have different folders`test suites` inside `test` folder . These folders contains so many `.js` test files. Each test file invokes a separate browser.

Is their a way I can use single browser for all test files inside suite?

I have already gone through these links but couldn't find out a working solution.

1. http://nightwatchjs.org/api/session.html
2. http://nightwatchjs.org/api/sessions.html
3. https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#dfn-current-session

Some one provided solution at this link [Reuse the browser session for Selenium WebDriver for Nightwatch.js tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27026363/reuse-the-browser-session-for-selenium-webdriver-for-nightwatch-js-tests) but I am more intersting in storing running `browser session` in string and for next test file put a check to verify if there is already one existing session or not, if yes pass its value to next one and avoid creating/invoking new browser session.

Comment: any update on this? was you able to re-use the same browser session?